# Linux command pipelining understanding

Tags: linux, unix, grep, pipelining

I am kind of new to nerdy usage of Linux. I am playing around with pipelining at the moment. Can anyone tell me why this don't works:

```
ls | grep 2 | rm
```

(I tried to delete all files containing a 2 in their names)
the `ls | grep 2` part is working ( it returns all file names with a 2 in them )
why can't I pipeline these names now to `rm` to delete these files?

thanks four ur help in advance :)

Comment: Note that some commands will let you do this by appending a single dash as an argument, but [not all of them](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41828/what-does-dash-at-the-end-of-a-command-mean), and `rm` doesn't happen to be one. But, for example, I can remove unnecessary packages on my Linux with `pacman -Qdqt | sudo pacman -Rns -`, which means list all unnecessary packages then pipe them to the package manager as which programs to remove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rm` expects the file names as *arguments* whereas [pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29) sends the filenames to the standard input (*stdin*) of `rm`. You can instead do:

```
rm $(ls | grep 2)
```

to remove the files. This way the filenames are passed as arguments rather than to the standard input of `rm`.

I have used your commands to explain the problem. In general, [you shouldn't parse the result of `ls` command.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Agreed. That's rather due to parsing ls command. Added the link for that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how can I tell this? doesn't _stdin_-inputs and _arguments_ look kind of the same in a standard terminal usecase?

Comment: @ct2034 No. They are distinct. When you put some paramters *after* the command's name (*command arg1 arg2*) then they are arguments. In contrast, a pipe's output is *always* going to the stdin. Some commands are capable of interpreting stdin as arguments when  passed with a specific parameter `-` e.g. `echo '#include<stdio.h>' | gcc -E -`. But this is entirely upto each command's implementation whether they support this or not.